# Action class value passing one method to another method

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

The value is not passing from method one to method two shows null pointer exception Please help me with this.

In Struts2 action class contains two methods. One method produce a value which is used by another method. In jsp page I have two buttons. One calls the first method to populate the value. Another button calls second method in the same class and use previously populated value from first method and display values in jsp. But every button click the action class object itself destroyed and create new object for every button click. So the first method values are lost and can not be referred by second method. Please tell me solution for this.

Struts2 action class :

```
 public class CrudAction{

    private List<String> list;

    public List<String> getList() {

        return list;

    }
    //method one

    public String one(){

        list=new ArrayList<String>(); 
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        return "success";

    }
   //method two


    public String two(){

        list.add("three");
        return "success";

    }

}
```

struts.xml :

```
<action name="one" class="com.CrudAction" method="one">
  <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
// for second method
<action name="two" class="com.CrudAction" method="two">
  <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

in jsp :

for first method

```
<input  type = "button" value = "one" onclick = "javascript:location.href='one.action';"/>
```

second method

```
<input  type = "button" value = "two" onclick"javascript:location.href='two.action';"/>
```

Comment: Don't post same question multiple times. Store your list somewhere (e.g. session).

Comment: ya i thought of it too.. but is there any other way to do it...like rerendering some particular list or variable ... is it possible that struts 2 have some methods for it.. i m happy to hear .. if something exist

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with framework at hand. You need to store your list somewhere or post it from jsp.

Comment: k.can u suggest any other possible solutions other than session please.

Comment: Convince us you have a good reason to NOT use the Session

Comment: Thanks for ur replies.. i m k with session. but i m just want to learn is there any other possible way of doing it...

Comment: Sure there is. But every other way is worse. Save it on db or on a file then read it, or post the whole list through the request, inject it in the page, the post it back (but it can be hacked), or use localHistory, or sessionHistory, or cookies, etc... just use session.

Comment: Thanks @AndreaLigios for ur reply.. now i think using session is a great idea for my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering HTTP protocol is stateless The object that you create in first request cannot be referenced in the second request Hence there are 2 options.

1 .Create hidden input tag that contain the list id, so that when you request for the second time, the struts 2 method can get the id (as parameter). It is expensive to create it again but it depends on your needs

2 .Before you render the jsp in the first request, you can put the object in session scope using ActionContext.
eg

```
Map<String,Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("mylist",list);
in the second request you can access the object

Map<String,Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
List<String> myList=(List)session.get("mylist");


Map<String,Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.remove("mylist");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur detailed code explanations.it really helped me well. but one thing it ask me to add  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in this line                                                              List myList=(List)session.get("mylist"); tell me what to do for it.

Comment: It's asking for generics

Comment: yes.i gave List<string> even though it show to add @suppress.can u modify ur code with generics...it would great if u do that and much more helpful..